# Get Last ID with RETURNING Oracle PDO_OCI php

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Can I use the RETURNING clause PDO_OCI?  I've been advised to use this to get the last id of a field which is being updated with a trigger.

I found a tutorial which gets the ID with oci_bind_by_name, but that appears to be a function of the oci8 driver.  Is there something similar to oci_bind_by_name in PDO_OCI?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO employees (name) VALUES ('Jones') RETURNING employee_no INTO     :employee_no";
stmt = oci_parse($dbh, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":employee_no", $employee_no, 8);
```

http://from8to5.blogspot.com/2011/03/oracle-php-returning-clause-statement.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OUT parameters, you should specify the type if the data is not a string (CHAR, VARCHAR2, etc), ie

```
// assuming employee_no is an integer
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, 'employee_no', $employee_no, 8, SQLT_INT);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

For PDO, use [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('employee_no', $employee_no, PDO::PARAM_INT, 8);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks bro for saving my time